# In MVP what exactly is the View?

Tags: asp.net, mvp

Hey just actually wondering what the View consists of in MVP.

Is this the actual .aspx pages for example...or is it the Interface that the .aspx page implmenets i.e. IMyPage.cs

Just looking to clear this up cheers.

Comment: Its both the aspx page and the backing vs class

Comment: when u say backing vs class you mean the code behind ?

Comment: Yes, actually meant to say backing cs class.

Comment: Thanks man for getting back to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view is the actual UI in this case the .aspx page

Check out this link for more info.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx

Comment: It's both the aspx page and the backing class file. If the pattern is implemented correctly, there should be very minimal-to-no code in the backing cs file. It's purpose should not go far beyond the initializecomponent.